# Unity - use resolved Types as parameters in other resolved types

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm 8 hours into unity, and already have figured some things out, but I am not able to find an angle with this. I got a `IResourceManager`

```
public interface IResourceManager
{
    ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    string Path { get; set; }
}
```

and the corresponding type:

```
public class ResourceManager : IResourceManager
{
    public ResourceManager(ILogger logger, string path)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        Path = path;
    }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Futhermore

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{    }
```

and finally

```
public ResourceManagerController(ILogger logger, IResourceManager imageResourceManager)
{}
```

I want to behave the Logger and ResourceManager like Singletons. I got it to work as long there was no ILogger in IResourceManager, but I keep getting the "no default constructor" exception.

So far I have:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>("DefaultLogger", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    container.RegisterType<IResourceManager, ResourceManager>("imageResourceManager", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ILogger>("DefaultLogger"), "basePath"));

    config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

    // Web API routes ...
}
```

How do I have to Register my types so that the instantiation of ResourceManagerController ist successful and both `Logger` and `ResourceManager` are used as Singletons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to register a logger to be used as default you must not name the registration.
If you want all named registrations, let unity inject an array.

Either...

```
container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IResourceManager, ResourceManager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ILogger>(), "basePath"));
```

and

```
public ResourceManagerController(ILogger logger, IResourceManager imageResourceManager)
{}
```

or...

```
container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IResourceManager, ResourceManager>("imageResourceManager", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ILogger>(), "basePath"));
```

and

```
public ResourceManagerController(ILogger logger, IResourceManager[] allResourceManagers)
{}
```